# How to detect the linux distribution name in Neovim init.lua

Tags: linux, editors, nvim, lua

How can I detect in my neovim `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` configuration which operating system distribution nvim is running? I want different Neovim configurations on debian servers as on my fedora linux workstation machines.

- `vim.loop.os_uname()` only detects 'Linux'.
- Is there some builtin like the `/etc/os-release` file?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this in a kludgy way, but it gets the job done.

Just call the lsb_release [shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676113/lua-os-execute-return-value) to get your distribution info, and then pattern match for the cases

```
local handle = io.popen("lsb_release -i")
local result
if handle ~= nil then
    local result = handle:read("*a")
    handle:close()
    -- From here, match on whichever distro you're looking to handle
    result:match("Ubuntu") -- e.g. looking to handle Ubuntu
end
```

*If you need to handle a more general case, [this page answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295052/how-can-i-determine-the-os-of-the-system-from-within-a-lua-script) how to validate that your OS is linux before checking the distribution.

**I think technically lsb_release this isn't guaranteed to be installed on your system, but it's worked for me. Also, sometimes I get "No LSB Modules are available" errors (even though it proceeds to print the lsb info), that I can't explain or resolve.